# Parse string to remove filename suffix (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing

My PHP scripy receive a string from JS. And i need to parse it to ignore the resolution suffix the image come with, but preserve the filename.

More clearly:

I need to transform this string: `starbucks-logo-291x300.jpg` into `starbucks-logo.jpg` in PHP. But sometimes the filename may have a longer string name, like `starbucks-logo-2921x3030.jpg` and `starbucks-logo-291x3200.jpg`.The filename prefix may change, so i cant't make it search for "starbucks-logo". Sometimes the filename have no suffix, and come just as i need. And sometimes the file may come in another image extension, like png, gif, jpeg, and bmp.

I'm new to php, so if possible, be clear about the function i need to use, please <3

Comment: Sounds like a job for [regular expressions](http://regex.info) in [php](http://us2.php.net/preg_replace) which fits with your tags. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried?  And are you always stripping out anything between the last "-" and file extension?  That can be done with substrings instead of regex.

Comment: Your actual requirements aren't exactly clear here. Will the "suffix" always be two sets of integers, separated by a lowercase x? Will the "suffix" always be separated from the rest of the name with hyphens? Give us an actual spec (and also show us what you've tried, if anything), and perhaps we can help.

Comment: The suffix will always be "-???x???", two sets of integers.  I haven't tried much yet, i couldn't find anything that could point me where to start from in replacing and parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done:

```
$result = preg_replace('~-\d+x\d+~', '', $filename);
```